# How to map observable object with inner observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How to map observable object with inner observables?

Following is how I fetch details of an item. I want to map the received object with a property unwrapped.

```
              this.fetchData.getItemData().pipe(
                mergeMap((item: any) => {
                    return {
                        ...item,
                        images: item.images.map(id => this.http.get(baseUrl + link)) -->> I want to unwrap here. (it is an observable; that's why!)
                    }
                })
              )
```

**Here I'm mapping the inner property images which is an array to an array of observables!!!**

This is what I've tried:

```
              this.fetchData.getItemData().pipe(
                forkJoin((item: any) => {
                    return {
                        ...item,
                        images: item.images.map(id => this.http.get(baseUrl + link)) 
                    }
                })
              )


              this.fetchData.getItemData().pipe(
                mergeMap((item: any) => {
                    return {
                      ...item,
                      images: item.images.map((id) =>
                        flatMap(() => this.http.get(baseUrl + link))
                      ),
                    };
                })
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, setting an outside value of `itemResponse` and then using it later on.

```
import { mergeMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
let itemResponse: any;
this.fetchData.getItemData().pipe(
  mergeMap((item: any) => {
    // assign itemResponse to item be used later
    itemResponse = item;
    // switch to all images
    return forkJoin(...item.images.map((id) => this.http.get(baseUrl + link)));
  }),
  // spread itemResponse and assign images property to images value and return the object
  map(images => ({ ...itemResponse, images })),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of [Aggregating RxJS Requests](https://thisisuntapped.com/articles/aggregating-rxjs-requests.html) .

As there are are only 2 levels of request you could simply nest:

```
this.fetchData.getItemData().pipe(
  mergeMap((item: any) => forkJoin(item.images.map(id => this.http.get(baseUrl + link))).pipe(
    // At this point all previous results are in scope so format the result as required
    map(images => ({...item, images})
  )
);
```

If you don't like nesting, or for a more general solution, you could use the utility operator [concatJoin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-concat-join) (note that I was involved in its implementation):

```
// fetch all the data, with all results aggregated into an object
concatJoin(
  {item: this.fetchData.getItemData()},
  {images: ({item:any}) => forkJoin(item.images.map(id => this.http.get(baseUrl + link)))}  
).pipe(
  // convert it into the format you want
  map(({item:any, images}) => ({...item, images}))
);
```